# How to fetch subtitle file(.srt) from video

Tags: android

I am working on displaying subtitles in android video player. I have managed to do parsing subtitles from .srt file which is in assets folder. I used

`inputStream = this.getAssets().open("Breaking Dawn Part 2.srt");`

to fetch .srt file. Also I have displayed same subtitles while playing video. But now i want to fetch .srt file which is embedded in video already to show subtitles. I want to know how can I access `.srt` file with this way, So that I can show subtitles during video streaming even in android v4 below devices. Kindly help if you have any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean mkv files? or files that have the subtitles as part of the video? it's just that when you say "embedded in video" i think of it as if the subtitles are a part of the video, and not just optional ones.

if you do mean mkv files, you will need to parse the file itself. here are the specifications:

http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html#track

you might even use their libraries for this task:

http://matroska.org/team/source-code.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to show .srt subtitles with customized way. I want to display them by using text view & place their position anywhere as per requirement.

Comment: ok, so what is exactly the problem? just put a videoView and a textView inside a FrameLayout or ReletiveLayout, and position the textView according to your needs...

Comment: yes..i have exactly done that. But by reading .srt file from assets folder. Now i don't want to read it from assets. Can i fetch .srt file during streaming video from server?

Comment: Hope you got my problem. Please help if you have any clue.

Comment: yes, i think you should be able to do it. but it depends on the type of the file. you will have to read the specifications of the file. then, make the app read from the inputStream (and of course parse the data) to get the subtitles and also use it for showing the video.